# "Data type mismatch in criteria expression." ACCESS 2010 and C#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I'm trying to make a query in Access 2010, but it keeps giving me this error "Data type mismatch in criteria expression." over the line "dataCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();"

```
 String sql1 = "INSERT INTO Formulario (Numero, Localidad, [Parroquia o Institucion], Fecha, [Id Institucion], Comunitaria, Observacion) VALUES (@Numero, @Localidad, [@Parroquia o Institucion], @Fecha, [@Id Institucion], @Comunitaria, @Observacion)";
 mi_conexion.Open();
 //insertar tabla formulario...........
 dataCommand.CommandText = sql1;
 dataCommand.Parameters.Add("@Numero", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = numero;
 dataCommand.Parameters.Add("@Localidad", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox_localidad.Text;
 dataCommand.Parameters.Add("@Parroquia o Institucion", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = comboBox_instituciones.Text;
 dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fecha", "#" + fecha.Value.Date.Day.ToString() + "/" + fecha.Value.Date.Month.ToString() + "/" + fecha.Value.Date.Year.ToString() + "#");
 dataCommand.Parameters.Add("@Id Institucion", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Int32.Parse(label_id2.Text);
 dataCommand.Parameters.Add("@Observacion", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = obs;
 if(radioButton_comunitaria.Checked)
 {
    dataCommand.Parameters.Add("@Comunitaria", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = true;
 }
 else
 {
    dataCommand.Parameters.Add("@Comunitaria", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = false;
 }
 dataCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I dont know what could be the reason.....

---

I tried this:

```
String sql1 = "INSERT INTO Formulario (Numero, Localidad, ParroquiaoInstitucion, Fecha, IdInstitucion, Comunitaria, Observacion) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
mi_conexion.Open();
//insertar tabla formulario...........
dataCommand.CommandText = sql1;
dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Numero", numero);
dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Localidad", textBox_localidad.Text);
dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("ParroquiaoInstitucion", comboBox_instituciones.Text);
dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Fecha", "#" + fecha.Value.Date.Day.ToString() + "/" + fecha.Value.Date.Month.ToString() + "/" + fecha.Value.Date.Year.ToString() + "#");
dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("IdInstitucion", Int32.Parse(label_id2.Text));
if(radioButton_comunitaria.Checked)
{
    dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Comunitaria", true);
}
else
{
    dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Comunitaria", false);
}
dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Observacion", obs);
dataCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But it doesn't work yet -_-.....

Comment: You pass all parameters as VarChar. Are you sure that your datatable fields are all of type Text? In other words. What are the datatypes of your fields?

Comment: This is one reason to USE ALWAYS AddWithValue, because exceptions like this can happen, yes Add Method have better performance but who CARES, you are not working with set of 1 million records.

Comment: @mybirthname not at all. AddWithValue should be avoided also if you want to avoid subtle errors in the defintion of the parameter type. In the context of this question I really suggest to avoid AddWithValue unless you know exactly how AddWithValue creates the type for the parameter.  Better explained here: [Can we stop using AddWithValue?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: @Steve okay I'm always using nvarchar and I'm ready to bet that this missmatches happend really rare. I really love articles without any prove. Okay there was an article that VS is going to die in 2014.

Comment: @Steve, There are two opinions. One says that AddWithValue should be used whenever it's possible (i prefer it), second - do not use it anymore! I think *AddWithValue* is quite good, because it does make proper convertion ;)

Comment: @MaciejLos try to insert DateTime.Now in an Access database using AddWithValue

Comment: @Steve, i tried several times. There's no problem if you use ISO standard (**MM/dd/yyyy**) and when query contains **#** around date parameter ;)

Comment: `Numero` implies a numeric type, you are passing text; `Id Institucion` (2 words?? is passed as text after `Int32.Parse` (text-> int->text?). so there are 2 candidates.

Answer (score 2):

Use `AddWithValue` instead of `Add` method. Sql Server will decide what type is the data for you ! I'm giving you an example. Also OLE DB does not support named parameters, only unnamed parameter

```
dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", true);
```

You should set the parameters in the right order. Here is the source how to add parameters for OleDb in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: You're wrong in a place where you talk about parameter's name. Please, see my answer. You're right about *AddWithValue* method. By The Way: +1!

Comment: Sorry I don't see that this was Access DataBase you are correct :)

Answer (score 1):

Access database (even when OleDb is in action) does not know parameters which names start with **@**.

To be able to use parameters with MS Access database engine, use:

```
PARAMETERS [parameter1] type, [parameter2] type, [parameterN] type;
SELECT <FieldList>
FROM <TableName>
WHERE FieldName = [parameter1] AND ...
```

For further information, please see: [PARAMETERS Declaration (Microsoft Access SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208916%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Second way is to use non-named parameters:

```
SELECT <FieldList>
FROM <TableName>
WHERE FieldName = ? AND FieldName2 =?
```

But i prefer to use named parameters.

Answer (score 0):

OleDb wants that you add your parameters in the same order in which their placeholder appears in the command text. OleDb using Ms-Access accepts also parameters with name that starts with @ without problem (probably to ease the upsizing to Sql Server),  but you should absolutely respect the order.

In your code you add the parameter for the field `Comunitaria` after the parameter for the field `Observacion` This creates the mismatch problem because OleDb passes the value for Comunitaria to the field Observacion and viceversa. The field Comunitaria then receives a value that cannot be converted to a boolean (Yes/No) value.

Try to change your code in this way

```
if(radioButton_comunitaria.Checked)
{
    dataCommand.Parameters.Add("@Comunitaria", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = true;
}
else
{
    dataCommand.Parameters.Add("@Comunitaria", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = false;
}
dataCommand.Parameters.Add("@Observacion", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = obs;
dataCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

A part from this you should remove that spaces inside the parameters names. It could only give you troubles and it is not needed.

I suggest also to use a correct datatype for the Fecha field. If Access expects a Date don't try to build a replacement string like you are doing the insert inside the Access interface.

```
dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fecha", new DateTime(fecha.Value.Date.Year,
                                                          fecha.Value.Date.Month,
                                                          fecha.Value.Date.Day)
```

Comment: Access does not know what *@Comunitaria* means. Please see my answer.

Comment: Steve, have you tried your code? And please, be carefull when you say: "*you're totally wrong*". Most of OleDb databases uses non-named parameters which is passed by **?**. Believe me ;)

Comment: I have said **OleDb with MS-Access** accepts named parameters that starts with @. I don't need to test this code. I have thousands of lines of code that uses this method.

Comment: As per my experience, it does not work. Respect, Maciej

Comment: I've read your comments one more time. Maybe it works, because you pass parameters in order as they've been declared? I need to check it (but not today). Maybe the truth is somewhere beteen? ;)

Comment: @MaciejLos the order of parameters in an OleDbCommand is fundamental. The name is simply ignored by OleDb. On the other side, Access considers everything that is not recognized as a tablename or columnname as a parameter so you could put any name you want (in certain limits of course). For example, sometime happens that I mispell a column name and Access complains that a parameter is missing.

Comment: As i mentioned in my answer, if you pass them as named parameters (in a way i provided), the order is not important ;)